# Pandas: filling NaN values in a column, based on other column- Handling missing values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame `df`, with many `Student_ID`'s, but here I'm giving a part of the `df`, like this:

```
Student_Id       Exam_Date     feedback_given        ExamID
1001             01-05-2021       no                 physics:preparatory:1
1001             NaN              NaN                math:preparatory:2
1001             01-05-2021       yes                physics:midterm:1
1001             NaN              yes                Biology:preparatory:1
1001             02-05-2021       NaN                Biology:preparatory:2
1002             NaN              yes                physics:midterm:1
1002             NaN              yes                Biology:preparatory:1
```

How can fill `Exam_dates`using `ffill()` or `bfill()` or in *any other way* if possible so that I could fill the `Exam_Date` For `Student_Id`.

**Note:** In above `df`, `Student_Id ==1002` has `Exam_Date` as `NaN`, so I would want to keep it `NaN` itself and only fill for `Student_Id ==1001` (i.e, If any of the `Student_ID` has all `Exam_Date` as blank I want to keep it the same as `NaN`).

**Out-put** `df`:

```
Student_Id       Exam_Date     feedback_given        ExamID
1001             01-05-2021       no                 physics:preparatory:1
1001             01-05-2021       NaN                math:preparatory:2
1001             01-05-2021       yes                physics:midterm:1
1001             01-05-2021       yes                Biology:preparatory:1
1001             02-05-2021       NaN                Biology:preparatory:2
1002             NaN              yes                physics:midterm:1
1002             NaN              yes                History:preparatory:1
```

Thanks in advance for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `groupby` first and then `ffill`, i.e.:

```
df['Exam_Date'] = df.groupby('Student_Id')['Exam_Date'].ffill()
```

Output:

```
   Student_Id   Exam_Date feedback_given                 ExamID
0        1001  01-05-2021             no  physics:preparatory:1
1        1001  01-05-2021            NaN     math:preparatory:2
2        1001  01-05-2021            yes      physics:midterm:1
3        1001  01-05-2021            yes  Biology:preparatory:1
4        1001  02-05-2021            NaN  Biology:preparatory:2
5        1002         NaN            yes      physics:midterm:1
6        1002         NaN            yes  Biology:preparatory:1
```